# Error when submit a Webform with Ajax using Jquery

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, webforms

I am having a webform in my drupal. I am using the jquery Ajax submit method to submit it.

This is the code I am using.

```
$("#webform-client-form-59--3").ajaxForm(function() { 

$(".talk-region").html("<h3>Thankyou,</h3> Our representative will be contacting you soon.<br/><a href=\'#\'>Close</a>")

}); 

$("#webform-client-form-59--3").validate();
```

But when I check in firebug.. Its posting, but the response am getting is

```
302 Moved Temporarily
        5.2s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit a webform, or any form for that matter, with jquery try calling the .click() event for the submit button or call the .submit() function for the form object.  If it's properly 'ajaxified' by drupal (using the use-ajax class) the click on the submit button should def submit the form.

[jquery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[jquery .submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)